# Incoming traffic to docker tries to exit via wireguard tunnel

Tags: iptables, docker, wireguard

I have the following problem:

My server has a public static ip. So far so good. My plan is it to bypass a firewall with wireguard and still be able to access the server and it's services via the public ip. I got another server to act as the wirguard server, because it doesn't have any firewall restrictions. The first time I connected the wireguard tunnel on A (which is the server with the public ip) my ssh session stopped working. I was not able to connect to the ssh service of A via it's public ip. I was only able to connect via Server B and with the internal wireguard ip. How do I keep every service on server A accessible by A's public ip? Especially docker?

My first idea was this:

```
PostUp = ip rule add from PUBLIC table main
PreDown = ip rule del from PUBLIC table main
```

But the docker services stopped being accessible after this.

This is what I see with `sudo iptables -I FORWARD 4 -j LOG --log-prefix "RULE4:" --log-level 7` after I try to connect to a docker service.

```
RULE4:IN=ens192 OUT=br-ef854b642e53 MAC= SRC=My_home_public_ip DST=172.22.0.6(docker container) LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2300 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

RULE4:IN=br-ef854b642e53 OUT=wireguard-peer PHYSIN=vethf2383bb MAC= SRC=172.22.0.6 DST=My_home_public_ip LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=2300 WINDOW=65160 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

For me it looks like this:

Me -> A -> A answers -> Wireguard -> nothing

But it should be more like

Me -> A -> A answers -> Me

For every other traffic:

A -> Wireguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not fully what I want, but this is my temporary solution:

https://github.com/BrodyBuster/docker-wireguard-vpn

With this script I was able to connect some containers to the vpn tunnel without using --network container:container_name and with proper port forwarding. If a container now needs access to the tunnel, I can just add the vpn network to it.

There is still a few caveats:

First, you can't have the host wireguard and docker wireguard up at the same time. I am sure you can also archive this if you modify the script. However, we only need the tunnel on the host system sometimes. For this few moments I can live with turning off the docker tunnel and enable the host tunnel for a few minutes.

Second, this configuration doesn't survive a restart. Even though the containers are up after a host restart and even though it seems like the tunnel is up, you can't access the containers. You need to tear it down and rerun the script after a restart. This is a bit annoying.